# Show hotels (and near by places) by appropriate icon on Map in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit, google-places-api

I am using Google places API for getting places near by the predefined location.

It works fine. I am supposed to show PushPins for each place. For now, I am using default red pushpins for each place.

Now, I want to show appropriate icon for each place, for eg;
for Hotels, Restaurants, etc....

On android, my colleague developers do the same thing, by using the Google API response.

In iPhone, I am not able to find any such help. Is there any way to do that on iPhone ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not address your question. But, some work-around.

I have came across the similar problem.
I did categorized the data, and showed notations according to that, along with the condition.
Hope this code gives you some idea about how i did it.

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;
    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
        if (!view) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
            CustomClassAnnotation *desclosureButton = [[CustomClassAnnotation alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 31)];
            [desclosureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapAction:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = desclosureButton;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            }

        ((CustomClassAnnotation *)view.rightCalloutAccessoryView).annotation = annotation;

        if (((MapViewAnnotation *)annotation).type  == 1) {
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_type1.png"];  
        }
        else if (((MapViewAnnotation *)annotation).type == 2) {
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_type2.png"];
        }
        else if (((MapViewAnnotation *)annotation).type == 3) {
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_type3.png"];
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Best of luck...

Comment: Also, by this work around, icons that comes with the response to Google Places API, are not used directly, as you can see in the code.